# when using mat-label outside mat-form-field, accessibility doesn't work

Tags: angular, material-ui

When I use mat-label outside a mat-form-field, the accessibility doesn't work. I expect when I click the label, the input will be focused but I only can achieve this if I use label instead of mat-label.
My html looks like below:

```
<mat-label>First name
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        [value]="field"/>
 </mat-form-field>
</mat-label>
```

So if I replaced the mat-label with label, then it works, but not using mat-label. I tried a lot of variation of "aria-label" but that didn't help either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The "mat-label" is used within mat-form-field, purpose is to make the floating label when focusing on the input. You can use normal label tag to keep the accessibility

Comment: yeah if I use label only, it works. I just wanted to ensure I am on a right path.